# Adjusting countInStock based off of forEach() and filter()s

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to adjust my `countInStock` based off of qty ordered. In my `PlaceOrderScreen.js`, I have `items = item.map(product => ({ _id: product._id, countInStock: product.countInStock, qty: product.qty, new:(product.countInStock - product.qty) }))` where `item = cart.carItems`. Additionally, I have `products`, which is an array of all of the products that I have. I need to match the `_id`s from my `items` array with the corresponding `_id`s from `products`, and then make `countInStock` for that product equal to the `new` value for that `_id`.

This is what I have so far:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const item = cart.cartItems
  const items = item.map(product => ({_id: product._id, countInStock: product.countInStock, qty: product.qty, new:(product.countInStock - product.qty) }))
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { products } = productList;
  useEffect(() =>{
      dispatch(listProducts({}));
  }, [dispatch]);

products.forEach( x => {
    if (x._id === items.filter((y) => y._id)) { x.countInStock = items.filter((y) => y._id === x._id).map((y) => y.new) }}
  )
```

But I'm not sure if this is how I should be going about doing this. I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to update my `countInStock` values.

Format of Products

````
0: {additionalImages: ["additional-uploads/2022-03-11T06:15:24.926Zproduct-2.jpg",…],…}
additionalImages: ["additional-uploads/2022-03-11T06:15:24.926Zproduct-2.jpg",…]
countInStock: 3
createdAt: "2022-03-11T06:14:49.719Z"
name: "Bliss"
price: 50
__v: 5
_id: "622ae8d94bee11259a3b1756"

1: {additionalImages: ["additional-uploads/2022-03-12T23:31:42.703Zproduct-2.jpg",…],…}
additionalImages: ["additional-uploads/2022-03-12T23:31:42.703Zproduct-2.jpg",…]
countInStock: 7
createdAt: "2022-03-12T23:31:06.137Z"
name: "Blue"
price: 20
__v: 1
_id: "622d2d3a4bee11259a3b17ed"

```
````

Answer (score 0):

maybe use reselect ?

the idea would be :

```
const selectCard = (state) => state.card;
const selectProducts = (state) => state.products;

const selectUpdatedProducts = createSelector(
  selectCard,
  selectProducts,
  (card, products) =>
    products.map((product) => ({
      ...product,
      countInStock:
        product.countInStock -
          card.products.filter((cardProduct) => cardProduct.id === product.id)
            ?.qty ?? 0,
    })),
);
```

that way you would get the list of your products with their stock updated.

please note that this code could be unsuitable depending on volumetry of your products catalog, and or your data model, but you'll get a first idea to start with.